Laravel 11 Scheduled Job Runs But Handle Method Not Called?
When I run php artisan schedule:list, the scheduled job exists. When I run php artisan queue:work, the job runs successfully until it times out. But when I run php artisan schedule:work the console says something like
2024-06-15 09:08:00 Running [App\Jobs\Words\Datamuse\DatamuseAPIFetchResults]  15.90ms DONE

Which suggests the job has run successfully, but nothing actually happens? Here is my handle method:
public function handle(): void
{
    Log::info('Fetching results from Datamuse API...');
    echo "Fetching results from Datamuse API...";
    $this->datamuse->fetchAllSoundsLike();
    echo "Done";
}

I have tried adding a log message. When I run the scheduled job nothing gets logged?

check the app/Console/Kernel.php in schedule() if  there is the DatamuseAPIFetchResults. anything in failed_jobs?

I have the same problem with Laravel 11 (no kernel.php in Laravel 11):
this is my case practically the same
I try to see in table failed_jobs, but nothing the table remains empty, It seems like everything works, but in reality the handle() method doesn't seem to be executed (I also inserted a log into the method for verification).
I do not understand.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

When running the command, check if the execution record of the Job has been added to the 'jobs' table in Laravel. If it has been added, you need to run the php artisan queue:work command to execute the commands in the list.
